# Arango- AQL how sort is performed

Tags: arangodb

In AQL query, how is the SORT performed; after all the users (say 1 million records in users table) are fetched then the sort is performed?

`FOR u in users SORT u.name ASC return u`

Also if i have a AQL like:
`FOR u in users SORT u.name ASC LIMIT 10 return u` 
Here also my understanding is all 1 million records need to be fetched and then sorted and then limit is applied. Can you help me with understanding ?